# Generate a new list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose we have the following sample data

```
data = {{{10.4239, -0.0208131, 0.439032}, {10.379, -0.0194723, 
 0.737773}}, {{10.3581, 0.00106231, 0.84059}, {10.379, 0.0214038, 
 0.733933}}}
```

How can I create a new list containing only the first and second (or second and third) elements of the sublists? In other words how can I get this

```
data2 = {{{10.4239, -0.0208131}, {10.379, -0.0194723}}, {{10.3581,
        0.00106231, {10.379, 0.0214038}}}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also use patterns `data //. {a_, b_, c__} :> {a, b}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data[[;; , ;; , 1 ;; 2]]` gives the required answer. [(Ref.)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html)

Comment: Or `data[[;; , ;; , {1,3}]]` if I want the first and the third element, correct?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z yup.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z welcome!

Comment: You can also use `All` in place of `;;`.